# ccDrawLine drawing line at wrong coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm writing an iphone app using cocos2d 0.99.5,
I've this custom class:

```
@interface Head : CCSprite <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
```

I draw a line in this class' draw method like this:

```
-(void) draw {
   [super draw];
   glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);        
   glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);
   ccDrawLine(p1, p2);
}
```

p1, p2 are calculated like this:

```
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y);
.......
//change the position 
.......
CGPoint p2 = ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y);
```

Now the problem is the line gets drawn at different points other than p1, p2. I guess the points need to be converted to something but dont know what & how.

If I specify the same points manually, the line gets drawn at proper coordinates.

What is missing here??

Answer (score 0):

Everything you draw in draw function is relative to the node's position (in this case is Head's position). So when you change the position after setting p1 but before setting p2, the result is unexpected. If you try with manual points, the line is drawn properly only when the position is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting them to world space:

```
CGPoint p1World = [self convertToWorldSpace:p1];

CGPoint p2World = [self convertToWorldSpace:p2];
```